# JavaScript for loop in AJAX request not working

Tags: ajax

I have a bit of a problem with JavaScript for loop not looping. 
Here is the code:

```
if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
{
    if(this.response)
    {
        console.log(this.response);
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var output = '';
        console.log(data);
        for(var i=1 ; i <= data.length ; i++)
        {
            console.log('i got here');
            output += '<a href="'+data[i].platform_name+'">'+
                            '<div class="new-prod">' +
                              '<div class="flip">' +
                                  '<div class="front">' +
                                      '<img src="images/'+data[i].picture+'" alt="Image for '+data[i].product_name+'">'+
                                      '<p class="name">'+data[i].product_name+' ('+data[i].platform_name+')</p>'+
                                      '<p class="price">'+data[i].price+' Kč</p>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="back">'+data[i].description+'</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                               '</div>'+
                        '</a>';
        }
        console.log(i);
        document.getElementById('new-container').innerHTML = output;
        document.getElementById('lmbtn').setAttribute('data-offset',parseInt(offset)+8);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('lmbtn').textContent="Thats all";
    }
}
```

As you can see i´m making AJAX request to the server and get JSON as response.
My code gets to the console.log(data), it logs parsed JSON to the console, but for some reason it skips the for loop. console.log('i got here'); doesn´t log. At the end it logs console.log(i) is 1 and sets the innerHTML of the container to empty string.
Please, excuse my bad english and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use `for(var i=1 ; i <= Object.keys(data).length ; i++)`  or `for (var key in data)` inside your `for` loop as a condition.